# R: regexpr() how to use a vector in pattern parameter

Tags: r, regex, vector, vectorization, tm

I would like to learn the positions of terms from a dictionary found in a set of short texts. The problem is in the last lines of the following code roughly based on  [From of list of strings, identify which are human names and which are not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545180/from-of-list-of-strings-identify-which-are-human-names-and-which-are-not)

```
library(tm)

pkd.names.quotes <- c(
  "Mr. Rick Deckard",
  "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep",
  "Roy Batty",
  "How much is an electric ostrich?",
  "My schedule for today lists a six-hour self-accusatory depression.",
  "Upon him the contempt of three planets descended.",
  "J.F. Sebastian",
  "Harry Bryant",
  "goat class",
  "Holden, Dave",
  "Leon Kowalski",
  "Dr. Eldon Tyrell"
) 


firstnames <- c("Sebastian", "Dave", "Roy",
                "Harry", "Dave", "Leon",
                "Tyrell")

dict  <- sort(unique(tolower(firstnames)))

corp <- VCorpus(VectorSource(pkd.names.quotes))
#strange but Corpus() gives wrong segment numbers for the matches.

tdm  <-
  TermDocumentMatrix(corp, control = list(tolower = TRUE, dictionary = dict))

inspect(corp)
inspect(tdm)

View(as.matrix(tdm))

data.frame(
  Name      = rownames(tdm)[tdm$i],
  Segment = colnames(tdm)[tdm$j],
  Content = pkd.names.quotes[tdm$j],
  Postion = regexpr(
    pattern = rownames(tdm)[tdm$i],
    text = tolower(pkd.names.quotes[tdm$j])
  )
)
```

The output is with a warning and only the first line correct.

```
       Name Segment          Content Postion
1       roy       3        Roy Batty       1
2 sebastian       7   J.F. Sebastian      -1
3     harry       8     Harry Bryant      -1
4      dave      10     Holden, Dave      -1
5      leon      11    Leon Kowalski      -1
6    tyrell      12 Dr. Eldon Tyrell      -1

Warning message:
In regexpr(pattern = rownames(tdm)[tdm$i], text = tolower(pkd.names.quotes[tdm$j])) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I know the solution with **pattern=paste(vector,collapse="|")** but my vector can be very long (all popular names).

Can there be an easy vectorized version of this command or a solution that for each row accepts a new pattern parameter?

Comment: Maybe you need `stringr::str_locate(tolower(pkd.names.quotes[tdm$j]), rownames(tdm)[tdm$i])[,1]`. Check the `stringr` package (and `stringi` which `stringr` wraps) which offers basically the same `regex` base functions, but faster and more vectorized.

Comment: @nicola It works. Just note that `stringr` regex flavor is ICU, and it differs a lot from TRE (default base R regex engine) and also differs from PCRE (`perl=TRUE`) engine. BTW, if the strings that are search for are *fixed* strings, I'd suggest `str_locate(tolower(pkd.names.quotes[tdm$j]), fixed(rownames(tdm)[tdm$i]))[,1]`

Comment: Dave is duplicate in `firstnames`. Things might get messy?

Comment: @amonk: Perhaps, the next line fixes that - `dict  <- sort(unique(tolower(firstnames)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may vectorize `regexpr` using [`mapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mapply.html):

> `mapply` is a multivariate version of `sapply`. `mapply` applies FUN to the first elements of each ... argument, the second elements, the third elements, and so on.

Use

```
data.frame(
  Name      = rownames(tdm)[tdm$i],
  Segment = colnames(tdm)[tdm$j],
  Content = pkd.names.quotes[tdm$j],
  Postion = mapply(regexpr, rownames(tdm)[tdm$i], tolower(pkd.names.quotes[tdm$j]), fixed=TRUE)
)
```

Result:

```
               Name Segment          Content Postion
roy             roy       3        Roy Batty       1
sebastian sebastian       7   J.F. Sebastian       6
harry         harry       8     Harry Bryant       1
dave           dave      10     Holden, Dave       9
leon           leon      11    Leon Kowalski       1
tyrell       tyrell      12 Dr. Eldon Tyrell      11
```

Alternatively, use *stringr*  [`str_locate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.1.0/topics/str_locate):

> Vectorised over string and pattern

It returns:

> For `str_locate`, an integer matrix. First column gives start postion of match, and second column gives end position.

Use

```
str_locate(tolower(pkd.names.quotes[tdm$j]), fixed(rownames(tdm)[tdm$i]))[,1]
```

Note that [`fixed()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.1.0/topics/modifiers) is used if you need to match the strings with fixed (i.e. non-regex patterns). Else, remove `fixed()` and `fixed=TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I started experimenting with stringr::str_locate with some good results but I am not yet good at apply family of functions. Have a nice afternoon!